# array of strings selection sort (C)

Tags: c

i compile the c code below and i have found no errrors , but when i run it the programm stops and get this error : Segmentation fault (core dumped)  . i m trying do a selection sort to an array that has one string in any row . any

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define n 50

int main() {
    int i, j, pl;  /* pl = number of words */ 
    char words[pl][n];
    char *temp;

    scanf("%d", &pl);
    for (i = 0; i < pl; i++); {
        scanf("%s", words[i]);
    }

    /* bla bla
       bla bla  */

    for (i = 0; i < (pl - 1); i++) {
        pos = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < pl; j++) {
            if (strcmp(words[pos], words[j]) >= 0)
                pos = j;
        }

        if (pos != i) {
            strcpy(temp, words[i]);
            strcpy(words[i], words[pos]);
            strcpy(words[pos], temp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Iiiiin-deeeeeen-taaaaaaa-tion!

Comment: what about switching `char words[pl][n];` and `scanf("%d",&pl);` ?

Comment: You cannot allocate char words[pl][n] before you know what pl is.  And you cannot do it like that even after you know what pl is.  You need to dynamically allocate the storage using malloc.

Comment: and what about giving some space for `temp` ? Something like `char temp[n]` ?

Comment: Please turn on compile warnings. Always do this. The compiler would have caught several of your errors.

Comment: @jarmod **Wrong.** We no longer live in 1989. Variable-length arrays are part of standard C since C99 and an optional feature in C11. Please remove your comment because it is incorrect and misleading.

Comment: @H2CO3: actually I think he's right and you missed the point - the declaration for `words[pl][n]` happens before `pl` has been assigned a value. This can be fixed simply by re-ordering the first few lines of code.

Comment: @PaulR Yes, that's right; however, I was referring to the "And you cannot do it like that even after you know what pl is. You need to dynamically allocate the storage using malloc." part of the comment, which is incorrect.

Comment: Aha - yes, I see the second part now, so we're both right. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0; i<pl; i++);
```

Note that semicolon, The following block will only run once. So your "words" won't be initialized properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%d",&pl);
char words[pl][n];//put after the pl is determined.
```